# I have two tables (Person and Articles), how can I select all the articles by one individual from the articles table?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Person Table:

[image: Person Table]

Articles Table:

[image: Articles Table]

I want to select all the articles by one individual from the Articles Table. How can I do that?

Secondly, I want to select all the articles from one category (let's say all articles from sports category).

Lastly, all the articles that are considered favorites by the user?

How can I achieve these three things?

Comment: Post tables here as text, not as links to ephemeral off-site images.

Comment: To understand how these tables are plz see these two images in the above link.

Comment: Sorry How am i supposed to do that i really don't know? let me try.

Comment: Pro tips for asking questions here: (a) one question per post, (b) always make an effort before asking and **show us what you have tried**, (c) being a beginner does not exempt you from making an effort, (d) refrain from txtspk - if typing full words is too much trouble, Stack Overflow is probably not for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Article FROM Articles_Table
WHERE Person_Name In ( SELECT Name FROM Person_Table);
```

Or:

```
Select a.Article FROM Articles_Table a
INNER JOIN Person_Table p ON p.Name = a.Person_Name;
```

For MySQL upper query works fine, for SQL second query is like

```
Select a.Article FROM Articles_Table AS a
INNER JOIN Person_Table AS P ON p.Name = a.Person_Name;
```

Comment: Let Me try Thank you.

Comment: What is a in a.Article and p in p.Name? @Abhishek

Comment: alias names form tables

Comment: yup got it. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Thanks. Mark it if help full for you.

Answer (score 0):

Select all articles by one individual:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Name="Andy"
```

Select all article from one category:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Category="sports"
```

Select all articles considered favourite:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Favourite="yes"
```

Comment: Let Me try Thank you.